# Spark Scala concatenate 2 different data frames

Tags: bigdata, apache-spark, dataframe, scala

I have 2 different Spark data frames and I want to concatenate them together by columns with no join operations.
How can I do it using Scala?

Comment: Do they have the same schema?

Comment: I want to concatenate their columns

Comment: Generally, thats probably not a safe thing to do. Can you provide more details about what you are trying to do? Maybe there's another solution.